# Why does the TimeScaleDB Tutorial use SRID 2163 to save data

Tags: timescaledb

I'm following [nyc_data tutorial](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/tutorials/tutorial-hello-nyc#tutorial-postgis) from the timescale website. The dataset contains location data in SRID 4326 format, the "common" lat/long format. But to save the data, the tutorial converts the location data to [SRID 2163](https://epsg.io/2163) format. Why is this done? Is it more efficient to store this data in this format?

Answer (score 0):

Honest answer: no good reason. The demo was written by a non-GIS expert :)

But the great thing is that our docs are all open source and on github.  Want to make a PR?

- https://github.com/timescale/docs.timescale.com-content#contributing
- https://github.com/timescale/docs.timescale.com-content/blob/master/tutorials/tutorial-hello-nyc.md

Comment: Are you really using open source as an excuse to provide bad docs?